# Having trouble connecting to old version mysql(4.0) with python3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I got an error **"ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query"** when I tried to use the following python3 code to connect to MySQL database.

`mysql.connector.connect(user, password, host, database)`

Since my MySQL version is **4.0** and I found a document says that it doesn't support versions prior to 4.1.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

I can't change MySQL version of my device, is it possible to connect to MySQL 4.0 with python 3?